# Preference depending on user

Tags: android, authentication

I'd like to ad a multiple-user function to my app.
In the navigation drawer, you should be able to create a new user-profile and open an existing.
The purpose of this is that on a devices, used by different persons, each one can create an inapp preference.
So far I've got a preference activity, where you can assign a name and an integer variable.

So my question is:

How can I add a app-internal user "login" in my navigation drawer, so that by selecting a user-preference, the individual name and integer can be applied to the activities?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would first try to make a in-app login, try following this - https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-login-example/

it's not a secure way of checking the password but it gives you a basic start

Comment: Thanks for your response! Firstival, it doesn't need to be save, there's no personal data going to be stored. And is there a way to do this login stuff **inside the navigation drawer**, without a new activity/layout-login?

Comment: You don't need to create a new activity. What you can do is when that menuItem is clicked, create a dialog that can be customly designed with textboxes and buttons